# Path for downloads OSX 10.10.5 and xcode 7.2.1

Tags: xcode, macos, download

I made for our internal use a app with a today-extension. There I have access to download all files from our server. But I did not get the right path to save it. I want to save it in the users "downloads" or on the users "desktop".

My code to save the file is:

```
NSArray *docDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDownloadsDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *doc = [docDirs objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Page1.pdf", doc];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

This saves the file

```
/Users/itsMe/Library/Containers/com.myCompany.downloadApp.ToDayWidget/Data/Downloads/Page1.pdf
```

I want to save the file in /users/itsMe/Downloads/Page1.pdf or /users/itsMe/Desktop/Page1.pdf.

How can I do this? I tried without success modifying the path:

```
NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *homeDir1 = [homeDir stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSString *homeDir2 = [homeDir1 stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSString *homeDir3 = [homeDir2 stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSString *homeDir4 = [homeDir3 stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Page1.pdf", homeDir4];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `~/Downloads` folder add the `com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write` entitlement by setting `File Access` > `Downloads Folder` in the `Capabilities` > `App Sandbox` section to `Read/Write`.

`~/Desktop` is not accessible outside the sandbox.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the fast help.